# What do you call $x$ such that $\textrm{dim} f^{-1}(f(x))>0$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, notation

Let $f:V\to W$ be a morphism between varieties, with $\dim \overline{f(V)} = \dim V$. What do you call the closed proper subvariety $S$ of $V$ consisting of points $x$ such that $\textrm{dim} f^{-1}(f(x))>0$?

("Singular points of $f$" doesn't seem quite right.)

More generally, if $\dim \overline{f(V)}$ is not necessarily $\dim V$: is there a name for the closed proper subvariety of $V$ consisting of points $x$ such that $\textrm{dim} f^{-1}(f(x)) > r$, where $r = \dim V - \dim \overline{f(V)}$?

Comment: It is the exceptional locus of the connected part of the Stein factorization.

Comment: @JasonStarr : meaning what exactly, in the notation in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stein_factorization ?

Comment: In that notation, the morphism $f’$ is birational, and your locus is the exceptional locus of this birational morphism.

Comment: What one gets then is not all $x$ such that $\textrm{dim} f^{-1}(f(x))>0$, but only those sitting in components of $f^{-1}(f(x))$ of positive dimension, right?

Comment: Does one also capture the case $r>0$ in exactly the same way using the Stein factorization?

Comment: You are right.  I misunderstood the question.  You are looking at the inverse image of the image under $f$ of the exceptional locus of $f'$.

Comment: @JasonStarr OK - it's all fine for my purposes. But can one also speak of the exceptional locus of $f'$ when $r>0$?